# oAuth & signed requests on client side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter, oauth

I operate a site based around the Twitter API. Users log in, and the site makes customizable search queries on behalf of each individual user. Up until now, I had used a service that automatically assembled oAuth1.0a authorization headers and sent them via proxy. Recently, the service changed their business model and I can't afford to keep the service (my site is free for users).

My site is built with the MEAN stack and currently the customized Twitter queries are assembled on the client side (ex: specific twitter search terms). I understand how to assemble the header, but I'm concerned about the security of my consumer secret key. My question is: How should I go about assembling the header while not revealing the consumer secret.

Would it be best to:

1. Pass the user credentials to my express API, assemble the header there, and then return it to the client?
2. Pass everything to the express API, send the Twitter API request from the backend, and return the result to the front end?
3. Encrypt the consumer secret and pass it to the client side to build the authorization header there?

Besides the security risk, I'm worried about hammering my API with requests, as one user could make as many as 150 twitter api requests per 15 min. At some point I'd like to redesign my site to build and cache the queries on the backend, but I need to find a temporary fix ASAP.

Thanks!